# Azure Machine Learning Computes - Template properties - Required properties for attach operation

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-bicep

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.machinelearningservices/workspaces/computes?tabs=bicep there are the properties `location`, `sku`, `tags` and `identity`.

For me it is not clear whether these properties relate to the parent workspace or to the compute resource (e.g. as the there is also `computeLocation` or `sku` as far as I can see should have the same value as the workspace)...

It would be great when someone can clarify to which resource these properties and related values belong to (workspace vs. compute resource).

**EDIT:**
Also: which properties are actually required for attach versus create? E.g. do I need `identity` or `computeLocation` for attach, and if yes what is the purpose of it as the compute resource is being created in another context?

I also figured out that `location` as well as `disableLocalAuth` are required for the attach operation - why when the resource is being deployed in another context and only attached?

And why do I get `unsupported compute type` when checking for the compute resources via Azure CLI for the attached AKS?

```
{
    "description": "Default AKS Cluster",
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/xxx/computes/DefaultAKS",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "DefaultAKS",
    "provisioning_state": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "xxx",
    "resource_id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/xxx",
    "type": "*** unsupported compute type ***"
}
```

**EDIT-2:**

So based on the response from @SairamTadepalli-MT all the properties actually relate to the compute resource - what makes sense. Still, I don't understand the purpose of a few of these properties. For instance why is there a "location" and a "computeLocation" or what is the meaning of "sku" (e.g. I tried "AmlCompute" and provided the value "Basic" - but "Basic" is the "sku" of the workspace and for "AmlCompute" the size is actually defined by the "vmSize" or?...).

What brings me to the next point: the current documentation currently lacks a detailed description in which scenarios which properties can have which values respectively need to be provided (beside "properties").

This is also true for attach (i.e. providing a "resourceId") vs. create (i.e. providing "properties"): which properties are actually required for attach? For what I figured out it requires "location" and "disableLocalAuth" - why do I need these properties as I would assume "name" and "resourceId" (and maybe "computeType") should be sufficient to attach a compute resource? What is the purpose of properties like "sku", "tags" or "identity" when I attach an existing compute resource?

Finally regarding "unsupported compute type": not sure if your response really helps me. The AKS is successfully attached, so I don't understand why I get "unsupported compute type". This should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Before identifying the properties and their uses, we need to understand a small difference between workspaces and computer resources

**Workspaces:** The workspace is the top-level resource for Azure Machine Learning, providing a centralized place to work with all the artifacts you create when you use Azure Machine Learning. The workspace keeps a history of all training runs, including logs, metrics, output, and a snapshot of your scripts. You use this information to determine which training run produces the best model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-workspace

on the other hand let's check about computer resources

**Compute Resources:** An Azure Machine Learning compute instance is a managed cloud-based workstation for data scientists. Compute instances make it easy to get started with Azure Machine Learning development as well as provide management and enterprise readiness capabilities for IT administrators.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-compute-instance

***Workspaces*** are used to work on machine learning resources and **identify all the operations** which are **completed** and **in progress** or even **failed as a log.**

***Compute resources*** are the kind of **administration operations** which can **handle the authority** on the resource which was shared and created.

Moving on to the next part of the question. Regarding the properties.

***Location:*** This is used to identify where the compute resources are created for ML operations. Comes under compute resources.

***SKU:*** This is regarding the tier and price of each tier which we have chosen in our subscription. This is related to the computer resources.

***Tags:*** Each resource created need to be recognized. Tags are compute resource identifiers.

***Identity:*** Subscription details of the compute resource. This can be further need to be used with workspace which deploying ML application.

***Location:***: The location where the parent code is located. Where the output is stored will be defined

***disableLocalAuth:*** Azure Automation provides Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) authentication support for all Automation service public endpoints. This critical security enhancement removes certificate dependencies and gives organizations control to disable local authentication methods. This feature provides you with seamless integration when centralized control and management of identities and resource credentials through Azure AD is required.

***unsupported compute type:*** Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) clusters, you might occasionally come across problems. Refer the link mentioned below for better trouble shooting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for your response. See "EDIT-2".

Comment: The unsupported computer type error will be raised with the version errors too. Kindly check the below documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster
Use GPUs for compute-intensive workloads on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster
These two documents can help you out to solve the problem.